# What type of object does each column contain: getting more detail than dtypes

Tags: pandas

I often find myself changing the types of data in columns of my dataframes, converting between datetime and timedelta types, or string and time etc. So I need a way to check which data type each of my columns has.

df.dtypes is fine for numeric object types, but for everything else just shows 'object'. So how can I find out what kind of object?

Comment: I think that's kind of the point, pandas doesn't know what kind of object it is and stores it as a sort of blob.

Comment: timedelta64 and datetime64 are full fledged dtypes - these are NOT represented as object at all - pls show a sample where you need converting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect one of the cells to find the type.

```
import pandas as pd
#assume some kind of string and int data
records = [["a",1], ["b",2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df.dtypes
>0    object
>1     int64
>dtype: object
```

So pandas knows that column 1 is integer storage but column zero is shown as object.

```
df[0].dtype
>dtype('O')
```

This still shows "Object" storage.

```
type(df[0][0])
>str
```

Voila.

Of course, this depends on your exact data structure. If you've got NaNs anywhere in the column then it sometimes plays havoc with the converted type (havoc as in its not always clear why it ends up as object storage).